# Vue components don't get attached if transcluded in parent components that have `v-if`

Tags: vue.js

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/6Lt7kc94/3/

parent component

```
<div v-component="child">
    <div v-component="transcluded"></div>
</div>
```

child component (visible is hardcoded to `true`)

```
<div v-if="visible">
    <content></content>
</div>
```

transcluded component

```
var globals = {};
var transcludedComponent = Vue.extend({
    template: "<div>blarg</div>",
    compiled: function () {
        globals.el = this.$el;
        // globals.el ends up inside a #document-fragment
    },
    attached: function () {
        alert('attached');
    }
});
```

The transcluded component is rendered in the DOM but the `attached` event never fires.

If `v-if="visible"` is deleted then everything works.

Am I using this incorrectly or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

It works if you use `v-show` instead of `v-if`.